# cascading dropdownlist as bound column on telerik grid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am not sure if anyone has ever come across an issue like this.

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have a Telerik Grid control, which has the first 2 columns as dropdownlists. I have the editor template for each of these columns as telerik dropdownlists. These dropdownlists are in user control (.ascx) files. The code for the ascx files is below:

User Control 1:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

<%=Html.Telerik().DropDownListFor(m => m)
             .BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["AccountTypeSelectList"], "lookUpCode", "description"))

%>
```

User Control 2:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>


<%=Html.Telerik().DropDownListFor(m => m)
             .BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["CreditAgenciesSelectList"], "description", "description"))

%>
```

The following is the code for my View where the Grid bound columns are:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<DealerOfferBaseKPI>()
                            .Name("T_KPI_CA")
                            .DataKeys(key => key.Add(o => o.DealerOfferRuleDetailId))
                            .ToolBar(commands =>
                            {
                                commands.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText).ImageHtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-left:0" });
                            })
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(o => o.AccountType).Title("Account Type").ClientTemplate("<#= AccountType #>").EditorTemplateName("AccountType");
                                columns.Bound(o => o.CreditAgency).Title("Credit Agency").ClientTemplate("<#= CreditAgency #>").EditorTemplateName("CreditAgency");
                                columns.Bound(o => o.PercentageAllowed).Title("Percentage Allowed");
                                columns.Bound(o => o.EffectiveDate).Title("Effective Date").EditorTemplateName("Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                                columns.Bound(o => o.ExpireDate).Title("Expire Date").EditorTemplateName("Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                                columns.Command(commands =>
                                {
                                    commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.BareImage);
                                }).Title("Actions");
                            })
                            .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                            {
                                dataBinding.Ajax()
                                    .Select("_SelectKPIBatchEditing", "DealerOfferManagement", new { filterType = "KPIcreditAgency" }).Enabled(true)
                                    .Update("_SaveKPIBatchEditing", "DealerOfferManagement").Enabled(true);
                            })
                            .ClientEvents(ce => ce.OnSave("GridValidation"))
                            .Selectable()
                            .Scrollable()
                            .Pageable()
                            .Sortable()
                            )
```

I am trying to make these 2 dropdownlists as cascading. The values of the first dropdown are **Residential, Commercial and Both**. The values in the second dropdown are **Equifax, Experian, TransUnion and Intelliscore**. When I select residential in the first dropdown I want the second dropdown to show everything but not Intelliscore. For all other values of the first dropdown, I want all values of the second dropdown to show.

I am passing in the values of the 2 dropdowns by using 2 ViewData objects from my controller.

With the code shown, the values in the selectlist are displayed in the dropdowns just fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the change clientevent of the first dropdown user javascript to add or remove element as explained [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/03/24/inserting-and-removing-listitems-in-dropdownlist-using-javascript.aspx)